# Unable to add a date time value in Cassandra DB? Invalid syntax error?

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, cassandra

#### Problem:

I'm currently trying to insert a date time object into my Cassandra database using the following code:

```
dt_str = '2016-09-01 12:00:00.00000'
dt_thing = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

def insert_record(session):
    session.execute(
        """
        INSERT INTO record_table (last_modified)
        VALUES(dt_thing)
        """
        )
```

However, I'm receiving the following error:

```
cassandra.protocol.SyntaxException: <Error from server: code=2000 [Syntax error in CQL query] message="line 3:17 no viable alternative at input ')' (...record_table (last_modified)        VALUES([dt_thing])...)">
```

## Background Info

I'm relatively new to Cassandra and I'm not sure how to go about this. What I'm basically trying to do is add an existing date time value in my database since an earlier version of the code is looking for one but it does not exist yet (hence, why I'm manually adding one).

I'm using Python 2.7 and Cassandra 3.0.

Any input or how to go about this would be great!

Comment: `session.execute("""INSERT INTO record_table (last_modified) VALUES(%s)""", dt_thing)` might be what you're trying to do, although I can't say for sure that Cassandra expects datetime objects in their default string format.

Comment: @Abdou I tried to change it to that, however I receive the following error below: TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not iterable -- I'm not sure where to go from this since I know the problem I'm trying to solve should be relatively simple.

Comment: Sorry. Try `session.execute("""INSERT INTO record_table (last_modified) VALUES(%s)""", (dt_thing, ))`. Didn't realize the second argument is expected to be an iterable all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered a [similar question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52805432/syntax-error-in-cql-query-when-trying-to-write-to-cassandra-from-python/52818405#52818405).  But the general idea, is that you'll want to define a prepared statement.  Then bind your `dt_thing` variable to it, like this:

```
dt_str = '2016-09-01 12:00:00.00000'
dt_thing = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

def insert_record(session):
    preparedInsert = session.prepare(
        """
        INSERT INTO record_table (last_modified)
        VALUES (?)
        """
        )
    session.execute(preparedInsert,[dt_thing])
```

Also, I don't recommend using a timestamp as a lone PRIMARY KEY (which is the only model for which that INSERT would work).